# AC Voltmeters: Transformer or Resistive Network

Tags: voltage, ac

Do most high resolution AC voltmeters use a transformer on the input, or simply scale down the AC magnitude with a resistive network?

Thanks!

Comment: No TFMR.  It measures peak, assumes sine and scales to RMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a digital voltmeter, there is no transformer. There will be resistive dividers. Exactly how the DVM adjusts scale will depend on the DVM, there are different clever methods, but there will be no transformer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for your help! (I realize there still should be isolation somewhere in the circuit for safety)